# No audio output from sound card to program

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, ham-radio

I am a ham radio op -- running a program called **fldigi**.  Works fine under XP, which I hate to use.

However, under Ubuntu 10.04, running ALSA and Pulse Audio, I cannot get sound from the sound card coming in from the radio to go to the program. 
 It comes through the headphones well.  I also cannot get any audio output from the program to the radio.

I have been around the block trying this, that and t'other thing -- messing with sound card configuration, etc., to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! New questions about [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29) Ubuntu releases are considered off-topic as per the [help/on-topic]. These old releases are unsupported and their use is not recommended. They don't even get updates for newly discovered security vulnerabilities, which makes using them risky. If you install or upgrade to [a supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Stable) and this question still applies, please flag and/or comment to request it be reopened.

Comment: You may be able to get an answer on [ham.se] however :)

Comment: How did you configure the program?